# Eclipse CDT not recognizing some GL functions, but compiles fine

Tags: eclipse, opengl, eclipse-cdt

I'm having a problem using Eclipse CDT, where it does not recognize some OpenGL functions.
I have the header included from

`/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers`

Some functions/enums are recognized by the indexer, some are not and provide no auto-completion. However if I command+click any of them (red or regular) I am taken to the proper file (GL.h) and the correct location of the function

I've checked, and those enums are indeed defined in that header.

[image]

Again compiles fine, but no code-completion provided, and areas are marked red as if wrong.

Comment: Have you included all the required OpenGL header files in your project? I guess that since you are using the OpenGL immediate mode (that I advice you to not do it since it is deprecated) you should include the required header files something like this:
    #include <GL/glu.h>
    #include <GL/glext.h>
    #include <GL/glx.h>

In particular, I think the basic declaration of the GL_QUADS constants are into the file "gl.h" which is included into the declaration of the file "glu.h"

Comment: This seems like a problem with Eclipse. Try recreating your project or cleaning it.

Comment: Perhaps, your problem is related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177569/why-does-eclipse-code-completion-not-work-on-some-projects)

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error quite often as well. Sometimes cutting the faulty line & pasting it back helps, but if that doesn't solve the issue a restart of Eclipse worked for me in all cases until now.

And the last resort solution to all Eclipse issue that cannot be resolved otherwise: Recreate the workspace and project, and copy only the source files into the new workspace. This has fixed most weird issues of Eclipse for many people, including myself.