# howto set up autocomplete for php in eclipse similar to java

Tags: php, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-pdt

i'm pretty new to php development and want to start using an IDE with syntax checking and autocompletion.
I'm used to programming java with eclipse and thought that the PDT provides similiar functionality.

In java if i type in for example: "new Arr" and press ctrl+space autocomplete suggests a list of possibilities with "new ArrayList()" on top.

but if i try the same in a php project, for example with "new mysq" and ctrl+space i get nothing. I would expect to get "new mysqli()" or similar recommended.

Is the described functionality not included in PDT? Or did i configure something wrong?
I did the "right click on project-> configure-> Add php support" but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Be sure to open the PHP perspective. 
I don't want to dissappoint you: Eclpise is an IDE for Java. To my mind to Java only. You cannot compare the PHP support of the PDT plugin to the native Java support. Unfortunately. :(

Comment: I'm in a php project and the PHP perspective. I hoped that PDT provides this functionality, maybe i have to take a look at ohter IDEs for PHP development :-(

Comment: I use Netbeans (maybe not the best) and it does contain fairly good support for PHP and Java. Otherwise as Christian Graf said, you need to use the PDT plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: I know i'm already using PDT but it doesn't do autocompletion of php library functions, i guess i misconfigured something.

Comment: Eclipse is a really great tool. It is not just for Java, it provides a great framework for many different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have some basic auto complete feature you can use **NotePad++** ([download](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.5.html)) for a quick and easy starter. This is a really great minimal program that can be used very efficiently to code in many different languages. It provides huge ammount of different functions. It is a must have tool for any developer.

I used Notepad++ to write ten thousands of lines of PHP code, it worked really great for me.

Otherwise **PDT also supports autocomplete**. Make sure that you have a **PHP project added** and then your are in a **PHP file** (.php extension). If you have Java autocomplete working in the same project then I think that you are in a Java project, try adding a PHP project, then a new PHP source file. Then PHP autocomplete should be working well in this source file.

Make sure also that you have **PHP perspective** selected.

I hope you can get by now starting using PHP! Have luck and good times using this great language!

[image: Eclipse interface]

Comment: I have the auto complete feature working also for mysqli library. What library would you like to use it for? Have you got the latest PDT installed?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this question: [Why does Eclipse code completion not work on some projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177569/why-does-eclipse-code-completion-not-work-on-some-projects)

I had to manually add this:

```
<buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
```

to the buildpath file of my project.